# Colorize cells based on editor

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I try to make a script for Google Sheets, to see what do the editors modify.
This is my script:

```js
function onEdit() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
  var User1 = email.indexOf("user1@email.com");
  var User2 = email.indexOf("user2@email.com");
  Logger.log(User1);
  Logger.log(User2);
  if (User1 = -1.0){
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#f4cccc')}
  if (User2 = -1.0){
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#c9daf8')}
}
```

Log looks correct:

```
11:42:08 AM Notice  Execution started
11:42:10 AM Info    user1@email.com
11:42:10 AM Info    0.0
11:42:10 AM Info    -1.0
11:42:09 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

But User1 & 2 got the same color(c9daf8). So I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

You need to use `getEffectiveUser()` instead of `getActiveUser()`

```
function onEdit() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
  var User1 = "user1@email.com";
  var User2 ="user2@email.com";

  if (email == User1){
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#f4cccc');

    }
  if (email == User2) {
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#c9daf8');}
}
```

Reference: [getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser())

In case if applicable for the particular data range:

```
function onEdit() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRng = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
  var User1 = "user1@gmail.com";
  var User2 = "user2@gmail.com";

  if (email == User1 && (dataRng == 2 || dataRng == 3) ){
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#f4cccc');

    }
  if (email == User2 && (dataRng == 2 || dataRng == 3)){
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#c9daf8');

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its work now. :) 
Have u any idea how i can set range for the script? I Only want to use it on B3:C1001 cells.  Thanks.

Comment: @NorbertFarkas I have edited my answer based on range as well

Comment: Thanks, @NorbertFarkas, don't forget to upvote the answer

Comment: Can't. :( :
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Now its stopped working, but idk why. useing the same accounts, but nothing ..:(

Comment: yeah. only works if i log in with sheet owner account. if i change owner works only with new owner...